# Migrate Enterprise Library 4.1 to 5.0

Tags: enterprise-library

We are using enterprise library 4.1 and smart client software factory 2008 to our application.
how we can upgrade enterprise library 5.0 and SCSF 2010 to our application.presently we are using visual studio 2008.

To upgrade what are the thing needs to be taken care.

Early help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In terms of Enterprise Library, the best case scenario would be to replace the 4.1 assembly references with 5.0 assembly references and change the configuration (to use 5.0 references instead of 4.1 references).  However, you could also hit some issues.

You should read the [Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0 Migration Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=7b8f9edd-7496-4232-9cbc-ce9476414956&displaylang=en) for a full description.  The [Breaking Changes](http://entlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=EntLib5ChangeLog#breakingChanges) document could also help you determine if you may run in to migration issues.

For the Smart Client Software Factory the approach appears the same: change the references and configuration to use the new dlls.  The [Web Client Software Factory 2010 Documentation](http://webclientguidance.codeplex.com/releases/view/45216) [download](http://webclientguidance.codeplex.com/releases/view/45216#DownloadId=121649) has a section on Migrating to Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Install the 5.0 package.
remove all the previous refreneces and add the newer ones generated.
You can refer the dlls by copying it to some folders or directly from the location where you have installed (C:\programfiles\Microsoftenterpriselibrary5.0)

I faced the below issues while migrating

Configuration errors in web.config files - some of my references in the web.config files were refering to the older version(2.0.0.0)(i upgraded from 2.0 to 5.0) and the publictokenkey="null"
so i pushed all the dlls to the gac and added the publicktokenkey from the c:\windows\assembly. which solved the issue

And another issue was regarding the microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.caching.cryptography- it was displaying soem weird error.- solution-the bin folder was having the old dlls and when tried to 
clean the solution the dll reference was still there. SO i deleted all those from the folder and rebuild again.

IT was initially having the logicacmg.enterpriselibraryextensions.logging which caused some issues- i used the microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.logging.configuration.rollingflatfiletracelistenerdata which could solve the issue.

Hope some one might get some inputs with this post